# Вернуться в главное меню | PyTelegramAPI

Tags: python, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Я создал тестового бота, сделал все кнопки, но не понимаю как можно сделать кнопку возврата меню..
Ниже прикрепляю код.

````
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('6287193261:AAGzmfb6RlLqWo2rZvEa9z4jAOl2Yqjex0A')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) # Объвление команды старт
def button(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('ТОП Игры', callback_data= "main_1")
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton ('Линия', callback_data= "line_1")
    item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton ('Регистрация', callback_data= "registration_1")
    item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Войти', callback_data="autorisation_1")
    item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Помощь', callback_data="help_1")
    item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Выберите язык', callback_data="change_language")
    item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Приложения', callback_data="apps_1")
    item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Зеркало', callback_data="mirror_1")
    markup.add(item1, item2,item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Главное меню', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data)
def check_callback_data(callback):
    if callback.data == 'main_1': # если юзер нажал на кнопку Топ игры
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton ('1', callback_data="arg1")
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('2', callback_data="arg2")
        btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('3', callback_data="arg3")
        btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('4', callback_data="arg4")
        btn5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('5', callback_data="arg5")
        bnt6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Главное меню', callback_data="arg6")
        markup.add(btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5, bnt6)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Топ игры\n'
                                                   '\n'
                                                   '1.Аргентина против Реал Мадрида\n'
                                                   '\n'
                                                   '2. Спартак против ЦСКА\n'
                                                   '\n'
                                                   '3.Собака против Кошки\n'
                                                   '\n'
                                                   '4.Крокодил против Акулы\n'
                                                   '\n'
                                                   '5.Цапля против Гадюки', reply_markup=markup)
    if callback.data == 'line_1': # если юзер нажал на кнопку Линии
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        btn7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton ('Футбол', callback_data="football_1")
        btn8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Хоккей', callback_data="hockey_1")
        btn9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Баскетбол', callback_data="basketball_1")
        btn10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Теннис', callback_data="tennis_1")
        btn11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Бейсбол', callback_data="baseball_1")
        bnt12 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Главное меню', callback_data="arg6")
        markup.add(btn7,btn8,btn9,btn10,btn11, bnt12)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Линия. 1', reply_markup=markup)

    if callback.data == 'help_1': # если юзер нажал на кнопку помощь
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        mainmenu = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Главное меню', callback_data='arg6')
        markup.add(mainmenu)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'TestBotbySoter приветствует Вас!\n'
                                                   '<b>Всякая информация</b>\n'
                                                   'Какая-то информация к первому пункту',parse_mode="html", reply_markup=markup)

    if callback.data == 'autorisation_1': # если юзер нажал на кнопку авторизации
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        mainmenu = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Главное меню', callback_data='arg6')
        markup.add(mainmenu)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, '<a href=ya.ru>Пройдите авторизацию на сайте</a>',parse_mode="html", reply_markup=markup)

    if callback.data == 'change_language': # если юзер нажал сменить язык
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        rus = types.InlineKeyboardButton ('Русский', callback_data='rus')
        eng = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Английский', callback_data='eng')
        ua = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Украинский', callback_data='ua')
        bel = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Белорусский', callback_data='bel')
        ger = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Немецкий', callback_data='ger')
        mainmenu = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Главное меню', callback_data='arg6')
        markup.add( rus, eng, ua, bel, ger, mainmenu)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Выберите язык, на который хотите сменить',parse_mode="html", reply_markup=markup)

    if callback.data == 'apps_1': # если юзер выбрал приложения
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        IOS = types.InlineKeyboardButton('IOS', url='https://apps.apple.com/ru/')
        ANDROID = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Английский', url='https://play.google.com/store/games?hl=ru&gl=US&pli=1')
        mainmenu = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Главное меню', callback_data='arg6')
        markup.add( IOS, ANDROID, mainmenu)
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Ссылки на наши приложения', parse_mode="html",
                         reply_markup=markup)

    if callback.data == 'arg6': # если юзер нажал на кнопку главное меню
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text='вы вернулись в главное меню', reply_markup=mainmenu())
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)```
````

Comment: вместо `reply_markup=mainmenu()` используйте `reply_markup=button(call.message)`